# How can I calculate my Broadcast Address in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to use bitwise operators to work out the broadcast address using PHP. I am facing an issue when using the `~` (NOT) operator to invert the subnet mask as it returns in string format.

```
// Derive from inputs normally
$ipv4        = '130.45.34.36';
$subnet_mask = '255.255.240.0';

$network = (object) [
    'ipv4'          => explode('.', $ipv4),
    'subnet_mask'   => explode('.', $subnet_mask)
];

$broadcast      = [];
$net_address    = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= count($network->ipv4) -1; $i++)
    $broadcast[$i]  = ($net_address[] = (float) $network->ipv4[$i] & (float) $network->subnet_mask[$i])
                        | ((int) ~$network->subnet_mask[$i]) +256;

printf("Network Address: %s\n", implode('.', $net_address)); // 130.45.32.0 (Expected)
printf("Broadcast Address: %s", implode('.', $broadcast));   // 386.301.288.256 (Unexpected)
```

Since `~$network->subnet_mask[$i]` returns a string, I've tired to cast it first to an `(int)` which has caused the unexpected result - without this cast, I get a `string + int` conversion error. I assume I need a different datatype, any help appreciated. My expected Broadcast Address is: `130.45.47.255`.

EDIT #1: I have tried to use `(float)` casts, which resulted in the same output.

Comment: `(~(int)$network->subnet_mask[$i])` ?

Comment: This worked, I did not think that I needed to invert the bits after the cast from string to decimal but logically that makes sense to do. Please feel free to create an answer, I'll mark it as soon as I can @jibsteroos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the conversion functions to perform bitwise operations on long integers and then convert back to IP and you don't need all the exploding, looping etc.

Swap the bits that are set/not set in the subnet mask with `~ NOT` to get the wildcard mask and then `| OR` that with the IP address:

```
$broadcast = long2ip(ip2long($ipv4) | ~ip2long($subnet_mask));
```

For the network just `& AND` the IP address and subnet mask:

```
$network = long2ip(ip2long($ipv4) & ip2long($subnet_mask));
```

Comment: Thanks, that beats [what I've just done](https://3v4l.org/9ItZ3). I had no clue `long2ip` was a built-in-function - thanks!

Comment: I have been doing network architecture and PHP separately for many years and I always look for the quickest easiest way. ;-)

Comment: I'm new into networking, I'm more getting my head around Docker/K8's but each use networking in their containers/pods so I'm just creating tools because I find practically doing things helps me learn and why not use the awesome PHP to build them. Production wise, you're spot on for using the quickest, easiest way and now I know a function exists for IP to binary!